# Storing associations in variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I am trying to make a method polymorphic so that it can access different models associations, but treat them the same

```
module Unitable

    # Adds new units without duplication
    def add_units(type, units = {}) 
        if type.downcase == "army"
            relationships = self.members
        elsif type.downcase == "character"
            relationships = self.owns
        end

        units.each do |name, amount| 
            unit = Unit.find_by(name: name)
            if relationships.where(unit_id: unit.id).first.nil?
                relationships.create(unit_id: unit.id, amount: amount) #<--- This is where the error occurs
            else
                relationship = relationships.find_by(unit_id: unit.id) 
                original_amount = relationship.amount
                new_amount = amount + original_amount
                relationship.update_attribute(:amount, new_amount)
            end
        end
    end

end
```

This throws

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This is the root method

```
def gen_starting_units
    credit = 9
    #transaction do
        units = Unit.tagged_with(["#{race}", "1"]).sample(2)
        while credit > 0
            unit = units.sample
            if unit.cost <= credit
                self.army.add_units("army", unit.name => 1)
                credit -= unit.cost
            end                         
        end         
    #end
end
```

Comment: It would be better if you can show us the stacktrace from the error and the code where the Unitable module is being used

Comment: It seems that you have an error happened before or inside (such as `before_save`, `before_create` callbacks) `relationships.create` that caused the transaction to abort, you have to find it. The full log of stacktrace can help a lot. In addition, you should show the code of `relationships`. One possible problem is that one of you callback `before_save` or `before_create` returns `false` or `nil`.

Comment: the "relationships" is just a polymorphic variable storing the has_many association of either the Army or Character model. I'm not sure where I can find the full backtrace, and also, the error seems to come and go, sometimes I can call the methods multiple times with no errors appearing, and others it will appear every time